# physijs -> physijs_worker.js -> ERROR: "runtime not defined"

Tags: javascript, three.js, runtime, physijs

I´m fairly conversant with three.js (I teach a class on it, tho I'm otherwise no webdevwiz) and I want to add physics with physijs.

Forked a copy and am trying to run the Jenga example: The blocks appear and then, after what seems like a variable time, they vanish, and the (Chrome) console spits out:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: Runtime is not defined" which I trace back to line 302 in the physijs_worker.js:

world.setInternalTickCallback( Runtime.addFunction( reportInternalTick ) );

Here's my page: 
http://card.gda.itesm.mx/mark/baldridge/jenga.html

Three hours of searching the net (and twiddling) have moved me not one inch - 
Can you help? Do it for the children! (or the kudos, either way!)

I'm stumped.

- Marqso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a pull on the physijs github repo.  I reported this a few hours ago and it's fixed now.